# Adding datetime to MySQL database PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How do I go about adding a clock in time to mysql database from php script. Here i have php script to detect user login, and im wondering how i go about adding the datatime of when the user clicks on the clockin button and saving it to the mysql database???

```
include 'config.php';
mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database)or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST["clockin"])){
    //get form data
    $myusername = ($_POST["username"]);
    $mypassword = ($_POST["password"]);

    if((!$myusername) || (!$mypassword) ){
        //check all fields are filled
        echo "please fill fields!";
        exit;
    }

    //check form in database
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$usertable} 
             WHERE username ='{$myusername}' 
               AND password ='{$mypassword}'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $account = mysql_num_rows($result);
    //check if user exists
    if($account == 1){
        $_SESSION ["username"] = $myusername;
        $_SESSION ["password"] = $mypassword;
        $_SESSION ["userrecord"] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);        
        echo "You have clocked in successfully!";        
    }else{
        echo "Wrong username or password";
        exit;
    }

$clockin = ("SELECT * FROM {$usertable} WHERE username ='{$myusername}' AND password ='{$mypassword}'"); 
            $addtime = "UPDATE {$usertable} SET clockin = now()";                   
            $time = mysql_query($clockin, $addtime);
        if($time){
            echo("<br>Time Got");
        } else{
            echo("<br>Time Failed");
            echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: You code sample doesn't show that you have made any attempt to implement this functionality.  Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? This code has no relation to the question. BTW, "To clock in" = "To log in" ?

Comment: i have a login system(clock in) im just wondering should i be using datetime or timestamp etc? i have the user loging in(clockin) and i need a way to get the time and date of when the clock in button is pressed.

Comment: is this the right format to use                                           $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`dateposted`) VALUES ('$date')");

Comment: Any one of then will work just fine. What you have to do is add a column to the user table (datetime or timestamp), then after you login in (or clock in, whatever) you update this field with some datetime function from the database.

Comment: there is no need to send the date from php to the database.

Comment: ive code up top to show what ive been doing, end of script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to have timestamp column in your mysql users table. Then you can use following query;

```
SELECT * FROM {$usertable} WHERE username ='{$myusername}' AND password ='{$mypassword}'; UPDATE {$usertable} SET timestamp = now();
```

That runs your select query, and updates the `timestamp` column.

Edit:

```
$clockin_addtime = "SELECT * FROM {$usertable} WHERE username ='{$myusername}' AND password ='{$mypassword}';UPDATE {$usertable} SET clockin = now() WHERE username = '{$myusername}' AND password ='{$mypassword}';";
$time = mysql_query($clockin_addtime);
```

Comment: do i need to give the timestamp colomn a length? like YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: Timestamp column updates automatically on every `UPDATE` so you don't need to put any value in it.

Comment: ok brilliant, do i need to refernce the timestamp coloumn name in the insert query? or does it just detect any known timestamp column and add to it?

Comment: No, it updates automatically, except in this case when you are just getting new time. So you can just do your inserts and the time updates automatically.

Comment: Well then things go more difficult. You need to change timestamp column to regular column(varchar?). The problem is that timestamp column updates **automatically**, on every query when it modifies the database. So you need to convert timestamp columns to reqular varchar columns and use them like `logintime = now()`, when login; and `logouttime = now()` on logout. Ask if something is unclear. :)

Comment: i think i know what you mean. Ive added code up top, can u take a look to see if im going along right line

Comment: Pretty close, i edited my answer, please check it. The problem was that you had to connect queries, not treat them as their own variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use time();  It will give you a Unix timestamp, which you can save in the database. So it would look something like this:
    $clocked_in = time();